# How to add a new group to user root?

Tags: root, groups

I am running a Ubuntu 16.04 as a guest for a Windows 7 host.

I shared a folder inside Windows and I should be able to see and open the file inside the Linux.

The issue was me, as root, could not open the file because the root is not in the `vboxsf` group.

From this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151113/how-to-change-primary-group), I just ran this command:

```
$ usermod -G vboxsf rootusername
```

After that I have lost the root privileges. I cannot use `sudo su` command, not open root files etc.

So how can I add the rootUser to `vboxsf` without losing all admin privileges?

Comment: What do you mean by `rootusername`? Root's username is `root`. Did you change the group for your account which you used to run `sudo` (presumably through the `sudoers` group membership)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a particular user to a particular group use:

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupname username
```

Here `a` is very important because otherwise the user will be removed from all other groups

Your problem is probably because you missed the `-a` part in your command

Comment: It should probably also be mentioned that modifying root's permissions or extending them is highly unadvisable in production environments.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem (-aG). It is only in a test environment to grab some files from windows.

Answer (score 5):

You can add any user to any group by typing:

`sudo gpasswd -a username groupname`